# Android Studio combined chart crashes

Tags: android, android-studio, charts, crash, combinedchart

I'm having an error and app crash, when pressed on chart. With single LineChart or BarChart I can press on the view or zoom.

With implementation `com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v3.0.2`

> Log: 12-12 22:01:50.108 3804-3804/com.example.jer.chart8 E/InputEventReceiver: Exception dispatching input event.  12-12
>
> 22:01:50.108 3804-3804/com.example.jer.chart8 E/MessageQueue-JNI:Exception in MessageQueue callback: handleReceiveCallback  12-12
>
> 22:01:50.108 3804-3804/com.example.jer.chart8  E/MessageQueue-JNI: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=12; index=-1

```
package com.example.jer.chart9;

import android.graphics.Color;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

import com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.CombinedChart;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.components.AxisBase;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.components.Legend;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.components.XAxis;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.components.YAxis;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.data.BarData;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.data.BarDataSet;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.data.BarEntry;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.data.CombinedData;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.data.Entry;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.data.LineData;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.data.LineDataSet;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.formatter.IAxisValueFormatter;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.utils.ColorTemplate;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private CombinedChart mChart;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mChart = (CombinedChart) findViewById(R.id.mp_Combine);
        mChart.getDescription().setText("This is testing Description");
        mChart.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
        mChart.setDrawGridBackground(true);
        mChart.setDrawBarShadow(true);
        mChart.setHighlightFullBarEnabled(true);

        // draw bars behind lines
        mChart.setDrawOrder(new CombinedChart.DrawOrder[]{
                CombinedChart.DrawOrder.BAR,  CombinedChart.DrawOrder.LINE
        });

        Legend l = mChart.getLegend();
        l.setWordWrapEnabled(true);
        l.setVerticalAlignment(Legend.LegendVerticalAlignment.BOTTOM);
        l.setHorizontalAlignment(Legend.LegendHorizontalAlignment.CENTER);
        l.setOrientation(Legend.LegendOrientation.HORIZONTAL);

        YAxis rightAxis = mChart.getAxisRight();
        rightAxis.setDrawGridLines(false);
        rightAxis.setAxisMinimum(0f); // this replaces setStartAtZero(true)

        YAxis leftAxis = mChart.getAxisLeft();
        leftAxis.setDrawGridLines(false);
        leftAxis.setAxisMinimum(0f); // this replaces setStartAtZero(true)

        XAxis xAxis = mChart.getXAxis();
        xAxis.setPosition(XAxis.XAxisPosition.BOTH_SIDED);
        xAxis.setAxisMinimum(0f);
        xAxis.setGranularity(1f);
        xAxis.setValueFormatter(new IAxisValueFormatter() {
            @Override
            public String getFormattedValue(float value, AxisBase axis) {
                return mMonths[(int) value % mMonths.length];
            }
        });

        CombinedData data = new CombinedData();

        data.setData( generateLineData());
        data.setData(generateBarData());

        xAxis.setAxisMaximum(data.getXMax() + 0.25f);
        mChart.setData(data);
        mChart.invalidate();
        mChart.animateXY(2000, 2000);
    }
    protected String[] mMonths = new String[] {
            "Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "June"
    };

    private LineData generateLineData() {

        LineData d = new LineData();

        ArrayList<Entry> entries = new ArrayList<Entry>();

        entries = getLineEntriesData(entries);

        LineDataSet set = new LineDataSet(entries, "Line");
        //set.setColor(Color.rgb(240, 238, 70));
        set.setColors(ColorTemplate.COLORFUL_COLORS);
        set.setLineWidth(2.5f);
        set.setCircleColor(Color.rgb(240, 238, 70));
        set.setCircleRadius(5f);
        set.setFillColor(Color.rgb(240, 238, 70));
        set.setMode(LineDataSet.Mode.CUBIC_BEZIER);
        set.setDrawValues(true);
        set.setValueTextSize(10f);
        set.setValueTextColor(Color.rgb(240, 238, 70));

        set.setAxisDependency(YAxis.AxisDependency.LEFT);
        d.addDataSet(set);

        return d;
    }

    private ArrayList<Entry> getLineEntriesData(ArrayList<Entry> entries){
        entries.add(new Entry(1, 20));
        entries.add(new Entry(2, 10));
        entries.add(new Entry(3, 8));
        entries.add(new Entry(4, 40));
        entries.add(new Entry(5, 37));

        return entries;
    }

    private BarData generateBarData() {

        ArrayList<BarEntry> entries = new ArrayList<BarEntry>();
        entries = getBarEnteries(entries);

        BarDataSet set1 = new BarDataSet(entries, "Bar");
        //set1.setColor(Color.rgb(60, 220, 78));
        set1.setColors(ColorTemplate.COLORFUL_COLORS);
        set1.setValueTextColor(Color.rgb(60, 220, 78));
        set1.setValueTextSize(10f);
        set1.setAxisDependency(YAxis.AxisDependency.LEFT);

        float barWidth = 0.45f; // x2 dataset


        BarData d = new BarData(set1);
        d.setBarWidth(barWidth);


        return d;
    }

    private ArrayList<BarEntry> getBarEnteries(ArrayList<BarEntry> entries){
        entries.add(new BarEntry(1, 25));
        entries.add(new BarEntry(2, 30));
        entries.add(new BarEntry(3, 38));
        entries.add(new BarEntry(4, 10));
        entries.add(new BarEntry(5, 15));
        return  entries;
    }
}
```

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1O9vU.png): [image]

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1O9vU.png): [image]

Comment: Source:https://www.studytutorial.in/android-combined-line-and-bar-chart-using-mpandroid-library-android-tutorial

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add `mChart.setHighlightFullBarEnabled(false);` or setting your own highlighting when clicking on bar chart,for more details check [this](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/wiki/Highlighting)

Comment: Awesome! Worked! Very grateful!